# Kind of energy in relation $E=\hbar \omega$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity

Is energy in this relation is only kinetic energy of the related particle or total energy of related particle containing both kinetic and intrinsic ($m_0c^2$) energies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only relative phases are meaningful in quantum mechanics, not absolute phases. In nonrelativistic quantum mechanics, we don't create or destroy particles, so including a mass just means multiplying *all* of our phases by the same factor $e^{kmt}$, where $k$ is a constant. This has no effect on the physics. For example, in double-slit interference, the waves from both slits feel this effect, so they interfere in the same way.

In relativistic quantum mechanics, you no longer have this freedom, and you do have to define $E$ as including the rest mass. Otherwise, for example, your wave equations wouldn't have the right transformation properties to be frame-invariant laws of physics.

Comment: Got it! A very exact answer! Based on the answer by Constantin to my quastion and my comment on it.

Answer (score 2):

$$E=\hbar \omega=\frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}$$

This is total energy. When it expanded in Taylor series in $\beta$, $E-mc^2$ is considered as the kinetic energy.

$$
\hbar \omega=mc^2+E_k
$$

Comment: But in a video by Susskind "Lecture 2 - New Revolutions in Particle Physics- Basic Concepts - YouTube" minute 36:30, he considers it just as kinetic energy... I'm confused. @Constantin

Answer (score 0):

for a massless particle it is the kinetic energy.